# Is there a marker folding method in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

As an ex vimmer I would like to create persistent folds based on markers inside comments (e.g. `// Section blabla {{{ , // End of blabla }}}` ). Is it possible in Intellij IDEA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest syntax is probably this:

```
//region
...
all your code goes here
...
//endregion
```

And you can also give a description at the `region` part:

```
//region Getters & Setters
...
all your code goes here
...
//endregion
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1, This looks much better than my solution. However I wonder why surround with still uses the `<editor-fold desc="">` syntax when this looks so much cleaner...

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I think it is because your variant also works in [NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomCodeFolds). It is not a standard but still used by more IDE:s. But I still prefer the one I showed.

Comment: I've noticed that it is filetype dependent feature. It works for java but not for xml.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ supports this feature, though the syntax is a bit different:

```
//<editor-fold desc="Properties">
private String foo;
private String bar;
//</editor-fold>
```

The value of `desc` attribute will be displayed when the region is folded. It can also be omitted entirely if you want.

You can easily surround selected code using *Surround With/Editor fold comments* action:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (OS X)
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Linux Windows)

You can also select to fold the custom regions by default in *Settings/Editor/General/Code Folding* by checking *Custom folding regions* checkbox.

---

Sources and additional information/screenshots:

- [Custom code folding regions in IntelliJ IDEA 11.1](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/)